# Русский шрифт в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Приветствую сообщество.

Столкнулся с неприятной проблемой в **tkinter**, а именно нелицеприятного отображения любого **текста на русском языке**(надписи на кнопках, лейблы, текстовые боксы). Основная проблема - невообразимо большие пробелы между буквами. Наиболее приемлемым шрифтом из **font.families()** оказался *clearlyu*, но и он, при увеличении шрифта, сильно искажается. При интенсивном гуглении данной проблемы, работающих решений найдено не было.

Решения типа "пиши на английском" и "переходи на PyQt", прекрасно понимаю сам, но необходим именно tkinter и именно русский язык.

Есть ли способы устранить эту неприятность?

Операционная система: Ubuntu 14.04

[image: Пример разных шрифтов]

Код примера(проблема возникает с любой подобной записю):

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
var1=tk.IntVar()
var2=tk.IntVar()
check1=tk.Checkbutton(root,text=u'Русский times 10', font="times 10", anchor=tk.W, variable=var1,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
check2=tk.Checkbutton(root,text=u'Русский times 13', font="times 13", anchor=tk.W, variable=var2,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
check3=tk.Checkbutton(root,text=u'Русский clearlyu 13', font="clearlyu 13", anchor=tk.W, variable=var2,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
check4=tk.Checkbutton(root,text=u'Русский clearlyu 15', font="clearlyu 15", anchor=tk.W, variable=var2,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
check5=tk.Checkbutton(root,text=u'Русский terminal 13', font="terminal 13", anchor=tk.W, variable=var2,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
check6=tk.Checkbutton(root,text=u'Русский terminal 15', font="terminal 15", anchor=tk.W, variable=var2,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)

check1.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)
check2.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)
check3.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)
check4.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)
check5.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)
check6.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

С уважением!

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код и какую операционную систему используете.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос, со шрифтом по-умолчанию так же криво отображается?

Comment: Добавил. Да, если не указывать font, русские слова пишутся также коряво.

Comment: *ubuntu17.04 всё выглядит красиво*.

Comment: @retorta, я Вам завидую белой завистью...значит нужно смотреть, что не так у меня в системе.

Comment: Не знаю в чем проблема может быть. Я пробовал tkinter под python 3 на Linux Mint 17.1 (или 17.2, не помню точно) пару лет назад, таких проблем не замечал. Разве что попробовать Ubuntu 14.04 на виртуалку поставить, может получится воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @insolor, хочу отметить, что я далеко не первый с этой проблемой. И, как я понял из гугления, она возникает не только на Ubuntu 14.04, а также на Fedore и Debian и Ubuntu ранних версий.